# HTML table not showing content in columns

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

A user can search for people included in a database introducing the search terms in an input text.
I am using following Ajax script to show the database objects received from JSON:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     
    // With JQuery
$("#ex6").slider();
$("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
});

 $('#keyword').on('input  keyup change', function() {
 var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
 if (searchKeyword.length < 3) {
      $('ul#content').empty()
 }
 if (searchKeyword.length >= 1) {
    
 $.post('search.php', { keywords: searchKeyword }, function(data) {
 $('#content').empty()
 $('#content').append('<table class="table table-hover"><thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Username</th></tr></thead><tbody>')
    
if (data == ""){
     $('#content').append('No hay resultados para su búsqueda') 
}
 
 $.each(data, function() {
    
      
 $('#content').append('<tr><td>'+this.nombre_doctor +'</td><td>'+ this.apellido1_doctor + '</td><td>'+ this.apellido2_doctor+'</td></tr>');

      
 });
  $('#content').append('</tbody></table>')  
 }, "json");
 }
 });
 });
 </script>
```

And this is the output when a user introduces a search term:

[image]

As you may see in the picture, the objects are not shown on the expected column.

What is wrong in the script?

Comment: As you know, sometimes troubled builded html tables can hide contents. I've tested this part of your code and everything seems to be ok. Based on this, I tend to think the matter is around json and/or java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `append` with a string, jQuery constructs an object and appends that. In other words, `append('<foo>')` is really `append($('<foo'>)`. The assumption in this code that append appends raw HTML is incorrect.

You want something like

```
var $table = $('<table class="table table-hover"><thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Username</th></tr></thead></table>').appendTo('#content');
var $tbody = $('<tbody></tbody>').appendTo($table);

$.each(data, function() {
    var $tr = $('<tr>').appendTo($tbody);
    $('<td>').text(this.nombre_doctor).appendTo($tr);
    $('<td>').text(this.apellido1_doctor).appendTo($tr);
    $('<td>').text(this.apellido2_doctor).appendTo($tr);
});
// Nothing with </tbody></table> , those elements already exist
```

Note that your current code includes a significant **vulnerability** as it allows everybody who controls your data to [inject arbitrary HTML and JavaScript into your website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). The use of [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) avoids this.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal and advices...I have change my code for yours, but now the data are not shown.

Comment: And how should I append all the information to $('#content') ?

Comment: @mvasco Just append the `$table`. I've updated the first line of this answer.

Comment: Thank you...it has been a great help to me

Answer (score 1):

You used a concate (+) function which packed all data into one column as a string. You should define 3 distinct columns to force a proper table layout.

```
<table width="100%" rules=groups border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table table-hover">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="33%" />
        <col width="33%" />
        <col width="33%" />
    </colgroup>
```

Now you have a solid structure to insert your data, by column. The `<th>`
 will line up the way you have written the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try building your table html as a string first, then use jquery's .html() to set it.

```
var htmlContents = "<table><tr><td>First column data</td><td>2nd column
data</td><td>etc</td></tr></table>";
$('#content').html(htmlContents);
```

That should do it.